# For a set with N members, what is the number of set partition in which each subset is either size of 1 or 2?

Tags: algorithm, set, partitioning, partition, powerset

I have a set with N members {1,2,.. N}. I like to know number of set partition in which each subset is either size of 1 or 2, i.e., cardinality of each subset in the partition is maximum 2. For example with N=3.. we have the set partitions of maximum size 2 are {1,2,3}, {(1,2),3)}, {1,(2,3)}, {(1,3),2}. However I am not interested in {(1,2,3)} since it is of length 3. Kindly tell me number of such set partitions for a set with N members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the number of such partitions of a set of cardinality `n` be `p(n)`.
The first element of the set can either be in subset of cardinality 1, leaving `p(n-1)` partitions of the remaining elements, or it can be paired with one of the other `n-1` elements, leaving `p(n-2)` possible partitions for the remaining elements. So we have

```
p(n) = p(n-1) + (n-1)*p(n-2)
```

Obviously: `p(1) = 1` and `p(2) = 2`

And therefore `p(3) = 2 + 2*1 = 4`

https://oeis.org/A000085 "a(n) is the number of partitions of a set of n distinguishable elements into sets of size 1 and 2"